# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\frac{9}{10}]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

> Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ converges uniformly on $[0,\frac{9}{10}]$

First I think we need to show pointwise convergence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N nx^{n-1}$$

Since it's a finite sum we can do the following:

$$= \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N (x^n)' =  \lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N x^n\right)^{'} = \lim_{N\to\infty}  \frac{x^N-1}{x-1} = \frac{1-1}{x-1} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $|nx^{n-1}| \le n(9/10)^{n-1}$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty n(9/10)^{n-1}$ converges (by the ratio test), by the Weierstrass $M$-test, the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$ converges uniformly on $[0,9/10]$.

Comment: Thank you @kobe. Would you mind to give a review for my proof as well?

Comment: @AlonAlon you've made a serious error in the last line. The third step should be $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^{N+1} - x}{x - 1}\right).$$

Comment: Oh you right. So basically we get the result $$\frac{-x}{x-1} = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: @AlonAlon no it's $$\frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using geometric series we know exactly what your series should be

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

Uniform convergence asked about the remaining terms and you can try to give uniform estimate

$$ \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty n x^{n-1} = x^N \left( \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
+ \frac{N}{1-x} \right) \leq  (\tfrac{9}{10})^N \left( \frac{1}{(1-\frac{9}{10})^2}
+ \frac{N}{1-\frac{9}{10}} \right) \to 0 $$

for all $0 \leq x \leq \frac{9}{10}$.